# Why can't I do skinning with Multiple Bone Branches?

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, skinning

Im currently doing GLSL Skinning. 
I imported my data from FBX and I have the Bone Hierarchy, the Binding Bone Matrices (TransformLink) and the Current World Space Position of the Bones.

The shader is like:

```
"void main(){\n"
"mat4   matPose  =bonePoseMatrices[int(a_boneIndices.x)]* a_boneWeights.x;\n"
"       matPose +=bonePoseMatrices[int(a_boneIndices.y)]* a_boneWeights.y;\n"
"       matPose +=bonePoseMatrices[int(a_boneIndices.z)]* a_boneWeights.z;\n"
"       matPose +=bonePoseMatrices[int(a_boneIndices.w)]* a_boneWeights.w;\n"

"mat4   matTransform  =boneMatrices[int(a_boneIndices.x)]*a_boneWeights.x;\n"
"       matTransform +=boneMatrices[int(a_boneIndices.y)]*a_boneWeights.y;\n"
"       matTransform +=boneMatrices[int(a_boneIndices.z)]*a_boneWeights.z;\n"
"       matTransform +=boneMatrices[int(a_boneIndices.w)]*a_boneWeights.w;\n"

"  mat4 btMatrix=   (matTransform*matPose); \n"
"  gl_Position=  modelviewprojectionMat * btMatrix * vec4(a_position,1.0);\n"                       
"    v_texCoord   = a_texCoord;\n"
"    v_position   = modelviewMat * btMatrix * vec4(a_position, 1.0);\n"
```

As you can see, this is a classic skinning shader, as seen googling.

While this works fine with a "snake" like degenerated tree (perfect animation for a bending block), it doesn't work with the second branch (a Y letter like model).

The bones get their world matrix by multipliing theirs model matrix with the parent matrix, and the Root has no parent, as the vertices will be multiplied by the mesh model matrix.

Why does it not work with Tree like Hierarchy?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work when you have an Y shape? Do you have parts of the mesh correctly animated or nothing at all? In any case, it's probably a problem with the way you are building those matrices on the CPU side.

Comment: hi, thanks. When I render a Y shaped (or more branches) the "second half" branch gets completely distorted, while the "first half" (and the "Root") renders perfectly.

Comment: now I'm working on the office, but at afternoon, I'll post some images so you can see the problem.